# How to use css modules with react and keep styles in the same (.jsx) file?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'd like to write my **css modules** in .jsx file. Similarly to **styled-components**. Here is an example of what I want to achieve (note that this is a single file):

```
// Cmp.jsx file

const styles = ???`
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
      
    .name {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
`

export default function Cmp() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.name}>Bob</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a library that allows to do it?

Can I import some internal function from webpack loader of css modules to use in place of `???`? If not then a hint on where I should look if I want to implement it (the code that actually does the import of css modules) would be helpful.

Note that styled components can be (ab)used to write in a similar manner but it won't help to avoid collisions of classnames/styles.

Comment: Could you just use a uuid generator or something, and pass it into styled-components, if you're too worried about conflicts in naming from unknown css? Do styled-components not automatically generate unique identifiers?

Comment: Was going to implement this myself but luckily have found exactly what I needed: `stylesheet` from [astroturf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/astroturf). Using version 1.0.0-beta.29 in my CRA app since it is the latest compatible with webpack 4.

Comment: You can always make an answer to your own question in case someone else stumbles across it in the future 